# Create a android Program login with Parse.com service

Tags: android, parse-platform

i developing an android apps by using Parse.com cloud service, i success make a login page with using database(but in Parse.com is call class or app). But i have a question which is when i create a new class(custom) name "User", even though i insert correct username and password, but cant' access to main_page. but i try create a new class by using Parse.com provided which name is User, this time i insert correct username and password and login success. So the problem is how can i know which class in Parse.com is select by program.

```
package com.example.android_project;

import com.parse.LogInCallback;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_login, btn_canl;
TextView txtview;
EditText et_username, et_pwd;
String username, password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create_acc_txt);
    btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    et_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_txt);
    et_pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd_txt);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            username = et_username.getText().toString();
            password = et_pwd.getText().toString();

             if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                 Message.message(getApplication(), "Please insert Username and Password");
                }
             else{
                 setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                 ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(user!= null){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else{
                            Message.message(getApplication(), "Username and Password Not Found");
                        }
                    }

                 });
             }
        }

    });

    txtview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String url = "www.stackoverflow";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
            startActivity(i);

        }

    });


}
```

}

In the code ""ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback(){" i know this is do validation username and password with cloud service, but can i specific to which database/class i need connect for do validation. Or program will select class automatic? Thank for everyone answer me, appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login/signin code of parse uses the build in User class of parse.
In your dashboard you can see User class on the side menu.

You can implement your own code for signin and signup using the regular ParseQuery functionality with your own custom class, but don't forget you'll have to handle the sessions,getting current user and more functionalities.

I think you are getting here a lot of free code why don't take it? Why do you need you own custom class? Maybe there is another way you can solve this.
(By the way if you wanna query on this table the class name is '_User')